# Multi-colored bookmarks

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

It would be neat to have favorites/bookmarks in different colors.  I often find that I want to bookmark messages for very different reasons.

- Answer later.  I can't write the answer right now, don't have the time.
- Read later.  When I have time.  Read one time probably.
- Reference material.
- Soft flag.  Benefit of a doubt for new members.  The quality of the question leaves a few things to be desired.  E.g. schematic/diagram is needed, otherwise the question is unclear.  The O.P. was prompted to post the schematic.  Revisit later.

The feel and UX could be not much different from starring messages in gmail.

**update:**
According to [this post on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176331/254079), the idea of more elaborate bookmarks has been going around.

Answer (score 5):

Another idea would be for the classification of favorites to be organized in (user managed) folders rather than colors.

The idea is when you click the favorite icon to get a popup to either add the post to an existing favorites folder or create a new folder (like done in ebay watch list).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in something like this-- a bit more involved than simply sorting favorite questions by tags.

I don't know that it needs to be part of SE to be effective, though.  I'm not thrilled about the bookmark idea, but somebody with a little ambition could probably throw something together with a good RSS viewer using the question feed links.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use your browser's Bookmark feature?

[image]

Comment: My bookmarks are cluttered enough as is, I don't want to make it worse.